# Gradle equivalent for Maven Java formatter that uses com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm switching a large project from Maven to Gradle.  Existing Maven project uses *com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin* to format the Java code.  Looked for the equivalent in Gradle.  Found https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.sherter.google-java-format, but it spewed a bunch of errors out, was really slow, and didn't generate the same output as the Maven plugin.

Also looked here: https://github.com/google/google-java-format - no help.

Is there a Gradle plugin which will give me same result as the Maven plugin?

Answer (score 1):

There is this other [Gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.youribonnaffe.gradle.format), which uses the Eclipse formatter. Maybe you can tweak it to achieve the same results as with the maven plugin you mentioned (I'm not using this plugin myself).

Note that it is an explicit non-goal of `google-java-format` and the corresponding Gradle plugin to be configurable. If you are not happy with the formatting style then this tool is probably not appropriate for you.

(if you have technical problems with my Gradle plugin, feel free to provide more details or [open a ticket on Github](https://github.com/sherter/google-java-format-gradle-plugin/issues/new))